# Understanding the definition of a ternary ring of operators (TRO)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces. Recall that a closed subspace $X\subset B(H,K)$ is called a ternary ring of operators(TRO) provided $xy^*z \in X$ for all $x,y,z \in X$.

On the other hand, an *anti-TRO* is same as  defined above except $-xy^*z \in X$ for all $x,y,z \in X$

> Since $X$ is already a subspace it seems both the definitions are same. Can someone please explain the difference?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The definitions are taken from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407250/example-of-a-ternary-c-ast-ring-which-is-not-an-operator-space)

Comment: I don't think you are reading the definitions correctly from that link.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Can you please explain them briefly? Apologises for troubling you.

Comment: They are considering the same  $X$ with two different operations, not defining two different types of spaces $X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I basically don't understand why $X=M_{n\times m}({\bf C})$, with ternary
multiplication $[x,y,z] := -xy^*z$ is not a TRO.

Comment: TRO and anti-TRO are the same set with two different operations.